# CapSentence issue

Tags: android

i m having Issues with s3

i`ve set input type of fields like

> Cap sentence
>
> Cap words
>
> Cap letters
>   The Scenario that was creating confusion is that 
>   when i test the App on Samsung Galaxy NoteII the app runs perfectly fine that means input type of the Edit text fields are performing their functionality accordingly

while the same app when runs on galaxy s3 the edit text fields are not working as their Input type 
both these Devices are XHDPi

> Res = 720x1280

can any body tell who to fix this matter 
Thanks 
Regards Usman Kurd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found Solution this might help others in Future 
this thing can be handled with the following 
go to Setting and then

> language and Input Type

option  and go to

> samsung Keyboard setting

and select the Option

> Auto capitilisation

now it will work perfectly in the App [image: S3 Screen1]

[image: S3 Screen 2]

[image: S3 Screen 3]